# Can't get process to stop reading data during sleep

Tags: c#, arduino, rfid

I am having a problem with my C# code. The code is designed to read RFID tags and based on the UID, tell a database what kind of process to start. The problem I am having is when I read a tag and set it to the required sleep, it stil reads tags and basically waits with executing the next procedure with the UID it wasn't even supposed to read.

**Code:**

```
string myConnectionString = "server=" + mysql_host + ";uid=" + mysql_user + ";" + "pwd=" + mysql_pass + ";database=" + mysql_daba;
MySqlConnection connect;
connect = new MySqlConnection(myConnectionString);
string query = "SELECT * FROM Tags WHERE tagCode = @tagCode";
AutodetectArduinoPort();
try{
    ArduPort.PortName = AutodetectArduinoPort();
    ArduPort.Open();
    ArduPort.Write("startmonitor");
}
catch{ 
   Console.WriteLine("comport did not connect.");
}
int delay;
while (true){
    string tagData = ArduPort.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine(tagData);
    connect.Open();
    MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, connect);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tagCode", tagData);
    MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    if (reader.Read()){
        string url = reader.GetValue(3).ToString();
        delay = Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetValue(4));
        command.Dispose();
        Process.Start(url);
        connect.Close();
        Thread.Sleep(delay);
    }               
}
```

Comment: maybe close the port before sleeping and re-open again at the start of the while loop

Comment: Are you getting errors? If so what are they?

Comment: No i`m not getting any errors, it just basically saves the uid it managed to read during the sleep period and executes the attached function when its done sleeping.

Comment: @KMoussa Your answer worked. i moved the opening and reading of the ArduPort into the while loop and closed the port as soon as the UID is saved to a string. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Provided I understood you correctly:

```
string tagData = ArduPort.ReadLine();
```

Covers a separate library. Called "ArduPort".
ArduPort is not effected by your "Thread.Sleep(delay);" Function.

You will have to modify the ArduPort code to implement a delay between reads, if you want to pause it's reading ability.

Whatever was picked up on the port, will simply be stored until your readline, fires again after a wait.

You need to change the scan code itself, to pause reading scans for your delay if this is what you want.

If I didn't understand you correctly, please provide:

1, a clear input example in your question.

2, a clear expected result in your question.

3, a set of possible constraints.

The more details you can give, the better we can tailor our answers to your question.

EDIT: My Answer still applies to a serial port component.

Comment: Sorry i did not mention the ArduPort declaration, ArduPort is a serialport handler. SerialPort ArduPort = new SerialPort();

Comment: @MichaelPlus I believe his answer is still accurate for SerialPort.  Your serial port will continue receiving data over the port until the buffer can't hold any more regardless of how many times you call sleep. You would need to configure the device to stop reading/transmitting until you tell it to start again.

Comment: Yeah gonna be honest here, i`m not the best c# programmer and i have no idea where to even start with that to be honest. Especially because i am using the build in serial library.

Answer (score 0):

this ended up being the solution thanks to KMoussa.
I`m now closing the arduport as soon as the UID is saved to a string. and opening it when the loop restarts basically.

```
string myConnectionString = "server=" + mysql_host + ";uid=" + mysql_user + ";" + "pwd=" + mysql_pass + ";database=" + mysql_daba;
            MySqlConnection connect;
            connect = new MySqlConnection(myConnectionString);
            string query = "SELECT * FROM Tags WHERE tagCode = @tagCode";
            AutodetectArduinoPort();
            while (true){
                try
                {
                    ArduPort.PortName = AutodetectArduinoPort();
                    ArduPort.Open();
                    ArduPort.Write("startmonitor");
                }
                catch
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("comport did not connect.");
                }
                int delay;
                string tagData = ArduPort.ReadLine();
                ArduPort.Close();
                Console.WriteLine(tagData);
                connect.Open();
                MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, connect);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tagCode", tagData);
                MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                if (reader.Read())
                {
                    string url = reader.GetValue(3).ToString();
                    delay = Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetValue(4));
                    command.Dispose();
                    Process.Start(url);
                    connect.Close();
                    Thread.Sleep(delay);
                }
            }
```